# Need help to code something specific on a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I’m new to Flutter and I’m trying to do something that looks like this for my app :

[image]

So that I can switch between them and they will display two different pages.
What’s this template called ? Can you link me to some websites that could help code it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called tabs or tab bar. Check out the documentation
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: const TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```